# Instant app - длительный черный экран перед запуском игры

Tags: android, unity3d, google-play

У нас проблема с мгновенным приложением. Когда вы загружаете игру https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oriplaygames.cutiepaws&hl=en

В начале видите черный экран в течение примерно 10 секунд, и только тогда происходит загрузка нашей игры, что может быть причиной?

Я хочу понять, что происходит в этот момент с черным экраном, скачивается ли он APK или что происходит, как я могу это исправить?

Можно ли заменить эту черную область какой-нибудь надписью?

Размер `APK` около `9,25 МБ`. Используются настройки для оптимизации из документации и `assetbundle`, проекта на `Unity`. Так же использовали плагин для Unity instant app, и делал в ручную.

video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szRJR-OFwOk&feature=youtu.beapk https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c5oMXizgT_Y9UFYUyYvaKVsqWOnLr0CS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: apk файл скачивается только с помощью GooglePlay. Ваша игра может долго запускаться, если на сцене, которую вы загружаете много ссылок на тяжёлые ассеты. Либо, в этот момент может происходить закачка AssetBundle-ов, уж не знаю, как вы это там реализовали. Я делал специальную панель, которая показывает прогресс их загрузки и использует кеширование, чтобы этого не происходило при каждом запуске.

Comment: Загрузочная сцена пустая, в ней толькореализация на скачивания AssetBundle и панель прогресса, а сама сцена в бандле весит не больше 6МБ